# Extracting a step from a text file and placing into a list with Python

Tags: python, list, slice

I am opening a txt and assigning every third word to go into a list called three.

I thought this would step correctly, but I am just getting the entire file as a list.

```
three=[]

with open('school_prompt.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.split()[::3]:
        three.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way of doing:

```
three = []
with open("school_prompt.txt", "r") as f:
    # read the entire file to process
    doc = f.read()
    # split the document
    word_list = doc.split()
    # extract every third word from the document
    three = word_list[::3]
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this making use of enumerate() to keep track of the count and every 3rd word you want:

```
three = []
with open('school_prompt.txt', 'r') as f:
   for count, word in enumerate(f, start=1):
      if count % 3 == 0:
        three.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

If file is big you can do next (it will read it line by line and append each third word to list):

```
idx = 0
three = []

with open('school_prompt.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            idx += 1
            if idx % 3 == 0:
                three.append(word)

print(three) # you list of words on 3rd position
```